# Where is the code for "tee" in Mac OS?

Tags: macos, tee

Where is the code for the terminal command 'tee' located in Mac OS?

**[Added]** Is it possible to read the exact code, that my mac is using (not the online codes)?

Comment: That is the exact code, just in uncompiled form.

If you want the binary, run `od /usr/bin/tee`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's BSD, not Linux, code.

http://www.pell.portland.or.us/~orc/Code/bsd/bsd-current/tee/tee.c

Answer (score 5):

By "code", I guess you mean source code, right?  See [there](http://www.opensource.apple.com/darwinsource/)

EDIT: I see the question has been made more precise.

See exactly in the "plain" BSD code [here](http://svn.freebsd.org/viewvc/base/head/usr.bin/tee/tee.c?view=markup) as a Apple Developer login (free) is required to browse their code.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.ss64.com/osx/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the source code of Apple's unix:
http://developer.apple.com/Darwin/

If it is up-to-date this is the exact code that your mac uses.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean, where is the executable? If that's what you're asking, it's at `/usr/bin/tee`. You can locate any command in your path by using the `which` utility. It will print out the full path to the command. For example:

```
$ which tee
/usr/bin/tee
$
```

If you're asking about the actual source code, a number of answers are already here that provide you with links to Apple's source code. The utilities themselves are split amongst a number of packages and there's no real index, so you'll have to browse the names and check packages that sound like they might contain the source for any given utility.